# Xamarin Navigation Page cannot convert

Tags: xamarin

(edited to add) [code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tI0fW.png)

I am very new to mobile app development and I am struggling to figure out how to navigate between pages.

When I use: 
Command = new Command(async () =>
await Navigation.PushAsync(new StackLayout()))

To go to another page, I get this error:

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout' to 'Xamarin.Forms.Page'

Comment: `StackLayout` as a layout control|class, not a `Page`-based class. Did you name your page's class `StackLayout`?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to create a navigation page that links to other pages that demonstrate different types of layouts.

Comment: You can create a Page that inherit contentPage, Then create a stacklayout in the contentPage like this link.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/stack-layout#positioning

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty much self-telling, `StackLayout` is not a `Page`. you will usually use `ContentPage` based class for this.

Comment: I'm sorry,  I'm very new at this. When I  right clicked my app name to add a new item,  I clicked ContentPage. Do I need to do something different?

Comment: You need to use instead of new StackLayout() the name of your page. If it is called like that then you need to use full path like new YourProject.StackLayout() as you probably somewhere have using Xamarin.Forms in which case compiler thinks you refer to the StackLayout and not to your page named like that.